# How to use generics with inheritance?

Tags: java, generics

I wrote some generics with inheritance, but cannot get it to work typesafe. My goal is to provide a general `BaseService` on that I can exection the `action(base)` method, no matter if the `base` object is a `Foo extends Base` or `Bar extends Base`.

The following does not work, why?

```
class Base;
class Foo extends Base;

interface BaseService<T extends Base> {
    void action(T base);
}

class FooService implements BaseService<Foo> {
    void action(Foo foo) {
    }
}


//usage:
//complains that the method is not applicable for the argument,
//and that I should change action(T) to action(Base). Why?
Base base;
getService().action(base);


//just to demonstrate the problem
BaseService<? extends Base> getService() {
    return new FooService();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)."

Comment: If so, what could I do about that to make my example work?

Comment: It already is typesafe. Too typesafe. I don't think you need Generics at all for this.

Comment: No it's not as it does not compile...

Comment: @membersound That proves that it's typesafe, 'too typesafe' as I said.

Comment: This isn't a good candidate for generics because you're always returning a `FooService` - being able to treat it as a `BaseService<Bar>` for example would break type safety.

Comment: Could you make a suggestion in how to refactor the code so that it works the way I intended, but without generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics exist for the purpose of static type checking.  As you write

> My goal is to provide a general BaseService on that I can exection the action(base) method, no matter if the base object is a Foo extends Base or Bar extends Base.

you indicate that you don't want any static type checking.  So to accomplish that, the argument type should be `Base` instead of `T`.

As the return type of `getService()` is `BaseService<? extends Base>`, the compiler can't even know what `T` is (other than that it's some unknown subtype of `Base`) so you can't call the `action` method at all.  But even if the return type of `getService()` would be `FooService`, the argument type `T` would be `Foo`, so you could not call it with type `Base`.

You should probably think a bit more about what you actually want the compiler to check by the use of generics.